# Java - File Reading - No such Element Exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have the following code that counts the number of user-defined identifiers in a file (e.g. user-defined variables and methods). So it needs to skip over tokens such as "main", "if", etc...

However, when I run the following program, I get an "No such element exception" at line 30 (Where I called the regexChecker() method). Here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class A1_104623455 {

    private static int idCount = 0;
    private static ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> identifierCnt = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static File file = new File("A11-input.txt");
    private static File file2 = new File("A11-output.txt");
    private static Scanner s;
    private static PrintWriter pw;

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        try {
            s = new Scanner(file);
            pw = new PrintWriter(file2);
            StringTokenizer st;

            while(s.hasNext()) {
                st = new StringTokenizer(s.nextLine());
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    str = st.nextToken();
                    if(!str.equals("int") && !str.equals("main") &&
                       !str.equals("printf") && !str.equals("return") &&
                       !str.equals("%d")) {
                            regexChecker("[A-Za-z_][A-Z-a-z_0-9]*", st.nextToken());
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + ids.size() + " valid identifiers");
            pw.print("\n" + ids.size() + " valid identifiers");

            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }
    }

    public static void regexChecker(String regex, String str) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        if(regexMatcher.find()) {
            if(!ids.contains(regexMatcher.group())) {
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
                ids.add(regexMatcher.group());
                pw.print(regexMatcher.group() + "\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I take out the if statement in which regexpChecker() is contained, the program works. I'm not sure what could be causing this error.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Edit:

Here's the contents of the A11-input.txt file that I was testing on

```
int main(){
    int number = 7;

    if( number%2 == 0 )
        printf("%d is an even integer.",number);
    else
        printf("%d is an odd integer.",number);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that within the while block the nextToken() method is called twice. So in the last iteration it is kind of expected to throw a NoSuchElement exception.

```
 while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
   str = st.nextToken();
   if(!str.equals("int") && !str.equals("main") &&
      !str.equals("printf") && !str.equals("return") &&
      !str.equals("%d")) {
          regexChecker("[A-Za-z_][A-Z-a-z_0-9]*", st.nextToken());
   }
 }
```